# how does float left affect transform translate

Tags: html, css

If I remove the `float:left` attribute from `.action-button` the transform animation doesn't work. Can you explain what is happening here?

Markup:

```
<a href="#" class="action-button animate green">Are</a>
```

Styles:

```
.action-button
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

.green
{
    background-color: #82BF56;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}

.action-button:active
{
    transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Codepen line 17: http://codepen.io/koriolis/pen/euAEg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `a` elements are `inline` elements, in that they align the the parent element and do not clear either side.

When you add `float: left`, It changes the elements from being `inline` to `block` but also removes the `clear: both` and allows for elements to be aligned next to each other.

You can achieve the same effect as a `float` by using `inline-block` if you don't want the tags to float on the page.

```
.action-button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/stewartside/pen/qdYZdN)

Answer (score 0):

1. tag `a` - default `display: inline`
2. `float: left` - display property is set to block
3. when you remove `float: left` - `a`  again `display: inline`
4. use `display: inline-block` instead `float: left`

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
.animate {
    transition: all 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}
.action-button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family:'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}
.red {
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #BD3E31;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #BD3E31;
}
.green {
    background-color: #82BF56;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #F2CF66;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #D1B358;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
}
.action-button:active {
    transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="action-button animate blue">Hello</a>
 <a href="#" class="action-button animate red">How</a>
 <a href="#" class="action-button animate green">Are</a>
 <a href="#" class="action-button animate yellow">You?</a>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3zs77779/)

Comment: can you elaborate I don't understand anything